# Installing specific versions of bind (apt-get)

Tags: networking, server, dns, docker, bind

I'm trying to set up a proof-of-concept network with a vulnerable DNS server (through bind9). I was wondering if there's any way to use apt-get to install older versions of bind9 (specifically 9.10.X or under) even though these versions don't exist using apt-get anymore?

The other alternative is to build these older versions myself, but I'm trying to see if there are any easier alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't even read `man apt-get`, which says, in part:

```
   apt-get [-asqdyfmubV] [-o=config_string] [-c=config_file] [-t=target_release] [-a=architecture] {update | upgrade | dselect-upgrade | dist-upgrade |
           install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  | remove pkg...  | purge pkg...  | source pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  |
           build-dep pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  | download pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]...  | check | clean | autoclean | autoremove
           | {-v | --version} | {-h | --help}}
```

The part you're interested in is "`install pkg [{=pkg_version_number | /target_release}]`"

Comment: I've tried that before. However, I'm talking about packages that don't exist in the package lists (i.e., if you run `apt-cache madison bind9` it does not include the versions necessary for my needs).

Comment: A decade of older versions are at launchpad.net. Download the package manually, then use apt or dpkg to install using the /path/to/local/package.deb